# JavaFX get capslock state

Tags: events, javafx, keyboard, capslock

In my JavaFX application, I need to know if capslock is on or not to warn the users if it's the case.

Before switching to javafx the following line was working well :

```
Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getLockingKeyState(KeyEvent.VK_CAPS_LOCK);
```

Since I moved to javafx, it only returns me the initial value of the capslock.

Do you have any other way to get it or to fix this line of code on javafx ?

Comment: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8090882 - long-standing (since 2012 ;) enhancement bug. There are several QAs around the issue, please do some research, there might be a work-around (or not), depending on your exact use-case.

Comment: All the posts I saw were before 2015 but I'm glad to see nothing changed since then :)
What a pleasure to work with a reactive support from them !!

Comment: it's open source, there is no _them_ - feel free to contribute :)